# Copy previous row's input value in new row's input?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Hey StackOverflow people,
I'm using a table form.

Here is a simplified version of my form:

```
<script>
$('#addrowbutton').click(function() {
$('tr:hidden:first').show();
});
</script>

<html>
<button id="addrowbutton">Add Row</button>

<form>
<table>
<tbody>

<tr>
<th>Select</th>
</tr>

<tr id="tr1" class="tr">
<td>
<input type="radio" name="color1" class="colorinput" value="red">Red 
<input type="radio" name="color1" class="colorinput" value="blue" checked>Blue
</td>
</tr>

<tr id="tr2" class="tr" style="display:none">
<td>
<input type="radio" name="color2"  class="colorinput" value="red">Red 
<input type="radio" name="color2" class="colorinput" value="blue"checked>Blue
</td>
</tr>

<tr  id="tr3" class="tr" style="display:none">
<td>
<input type="radio" name="color3"  class="colorinput" value="red">Red 
<input type="radio" name="color3" class="colorinput" value="blue" checked>Blue
</td>
</tr>

<tr  id="tr4" class="tr" style="display:none">
<td>
<input type="radio" name="color4"  class="colorinput" value="red">Red 
<input type="radio" name="color4" class="colorinput" value="blue" checked>Blue
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</html>
```

When the "#addrowbutton" is clicked, the first hidden row appears.
I would then want that new appearing row's radio input to have the same value as the previous row's ".colorinput".

Right now I have tried, before ending });  :

```
$('tr:visible:last .colorinput').val($(.prev('tr .colorinput')).val());
```

EDIT: Please, no clone/append solution.

Comment: So, what have you tried to get that working? Have you googled for something? Stack overflow will help you to write it yourself, but we wont' write it for you... show us what you've done so far and we can help you improve it towards a solution that meets all your requirements.

Comment: so if red is selected in the previous row then in the newly added row the red should be selected? is this what you meant by `same value as the previous row's`

Comment: Exactly! New added row's input should have the same value as the last visible (previous) row's input.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than having a number of rows pre-created hidden and then copying values... It would be better if you only have one row and clone the last row every time appending to the table.

First, you need to clean and fix your markup. You can't end a `<button>` with `</div>`! You can't have a `th` directly inside a `table`! Please read and understand basic HTML carefully.

Having that done, all you have to now do is to clone the last row and append that to the `tbody`. You also have to be careful about `name` attribute. Currently all your radios have the same name! This means that only one radio will be checked at any given time in the entire table. You probably would want to have different `name`s for `input`s in each row.

Once you are through understanding that thoroughly, coding becomes easy.

***Relevant jQuery code:***

```
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
    var $rows = $("#tab tbody").find("tr");             // find all tr
    var ctr = $rows.length + 1;                         // next counter will +1 of tr count
    var $newrow = $rows.last().clone();                 // clone the last tr
    $newrow.find("input").attr("name", "color" + ctr);  // change the name of inputs using ctr
    $("#tab").find("tbody").append($newrow);            // append the cloned tr
});
```

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/vc9ud1c7/***

.

Comment: Hi. You're absolutely right, I had a couple mistakes in the code... All fixed now! This is because I rewrote it here to make it simpler - my real code was alright. My first choice was to clone the last row as you suggest, but my real table holds a file input and the uploaded files won't get attached properly on new rows with that technique. Is it possible to stick to a hidden/show table? I need to do it that exact way. I'm sure it's not that hard to copy previous row's input, I just can't make it work!

Comment: Would you know how to achieve this?